# Get li class into a custom google tag manager variable

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

```
<div class="post-share-bar">
<ul>
<li class="share-on">Share on</li>
<li class="facebook">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp;u=www.Example.com" data-width="520" data-height="350" alt="Share on Facebook"></a>
</li>
<li class="twitter">
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Some%20text%20here;related=Example&amp;via=example&amp;url=http://example.com" data-width="550" data-height="510" alt="Share on Twitter"></a>
</li>
<li class="google">
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.Example.com" data-width="600" data-height="600" alt="Share on Google+"></a>
</li>
<li class="whatsapp"><a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="" data-href="" style="display: none;">Whatsapp</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to set a GA tag with a social track type and I need to pass the li class value for the network parameter when clicked, eg. Facebook, Twitter, Google, Whatsapp. The Action part of the social is fixed as article share.
The action target am going to pass in is the {{Page URL}}.

So how do I grab the li class value and push that into a custom variable?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a Custom JavaScript variable that takes the clicked element and returns the parent class, which would be the name of the social platform that you are looking for, something like this (assuming you have jQuery loaded):

```
$('.post-share-bar a').click(function(){
   var platform = $(this).parent().attr('class')
   // do something with 'platform'
)}
```